# Unable to create associated/ nested child record with "accepts_nested_attributes_for"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I get the following error on trying to create associated child record through parent using "accepts_nested_attributes_for":

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Survey question details survey can't be blank, Survey question details activity detail must exist):

Wondering if I missing any piece for creation of child record automatically?

Sample input: (first 4 keys in the below input are merged into the params hash before saving)

> {:organization_id=>"hardcoded", :activity_library_type=>0, :created_by=>"hardcoded", :updated_by=>"hardcoded", "activity_name"=>"s-s-28", "description"=>"", "content_path_url"=>"", "activity_status"=>0, "activity_type"=>4, "group"=>"group", "code_level"=>"code", "topic"=>"topic", "solution"=>"solution", "survey_question_details_attributes"=>[{"question"=>"Question1", "order"=>1, "question_type"=>0}]}

Parameters:

> params.require(:activity_detail).permit(:activity_name, :description,
>   :content_path_url, :activity_status,:activity_type,:group, :code_level, :topic, :solution, :duration_seconds, :survey_question_details_attributes => [:id, :question, :order, :question_type,:_destroy])

Below is the controller and the models (Each activity contains many question ):

```
class ActivityController < ApplicationController
def create
    # Merged additional_attributes hash to content_params recieved from front end (first 4 keys mentioned above in sample input)
    full_activity_details_record = additional_attributes.merge(content_params)
    response = ActivityDetail.create(full_activity_details_record)
  end
end

class ActivityDetail < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :survey_question_details, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :survey_id
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :survey_question_details

  validates :activity_name, :organization_id,
            :activity_library_type, :activity_status, :activity_type,
            :created_by, :updated_by, presence: true
  validates :activity_name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, length: { maximum: 55 }
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 160 }

end


class SurveyQuestionDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity_detail, foreign_key: :survey_id

  validates :question, :survey_id, :question_type, :order, presence: true
  default_scope { order(:order) }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared your views, Let me start the talking.

first of all, you have validated as presence true for the model attributes, hence you are getting validation error specifically.

```
####in SurveyQuestionDetail model
###this is causing the error => Survey question details SURVEY can't be blank
##you must either pass the survey_id as hidden field or comment it out
validates :question, :survey_id, :question_type, :order, presence: true
```

MOREOVER, in your view, you must use [fields_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for) for nested attributes in your forms

something like

```
<%= form_with(@activity_detail: show, local: true) do |form| %>
  # Show name and label
  <%= form.fields_for :survey_question_detail do |s| %>
    <%= s.label :number %>
    <%= s.number_field :number %>
    ##can also include hidden fields to add other model...survey_id
  <% end %>
  # Submit Button
<% end %>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: React is handling the form, the sample input I provided in the question is passed in as params from the react component to the controller. Is the input hash missing anything that is required when using "accepts_nested_attributes_for" approach?

Comment: @user3704527, as @Milind said in his answer, the `survey_id` is missing in your params

Comment: There is no Error specific to nested attributes but the only Error I can see is the missing attributes which is why the Model is validated as False.You need to take care of the attribute values you have specified in the model as mandatory else remove it

Comment: I need the survey_id to modify existing record, so my understanding was that during creating of new records when id's are not provided in the input hash,  the parent table's id and child table's id would be automatically created. Do I need to generate id's both parent and child table before passing to the controller?

Comment: When you want to create child attributes along with parent, you use nested_attributes_for and supply the child attributes in the fields_for in your form, as Parent is still not present, this is where the fields_for helps...if the parent is present, you can create a new instance like parent.child.new and then use it the fields_for like f.object.child

Answer (score 0):

I think the params created is incomplete. The params should come under :activity_detail key

```
:activity_detail => {
  {
    :organization_id=>"hardcoded", 
    :activity_library_type=>0, 
    :created_by=>"hardcoded", 
    :updated_by=>"hardcoded", 
    "activity_name"=>"s-s-28", 
    "description"=>"", 
    "content_path_url"=>"", 
    "activity_status"=>0, 
    "activity_type"=>4, 
    "group"=>"group", 
    "code_level"=>"code", 
    "topic"=>"topic", 
    "solution"=>"solution", 
    "survey_question_details_attributes"=>[
      {
        "question"=>"Question1", 
        "order"=>1, 
        "question_type"=>0
      }
    ]
  }
}
```